# Select closest element of type "h", e.g. h1, h2, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume I select an element using `$(mySelector)`. I would like to select the closest heading to it, so if the closest heading element to it was an `<h2>`, it would select that, but if the closest was an `<h3>`, it would select that instead. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried `closest()`, but of course that doesn't tell me just *how* close it is, so I can't tell it to choose the closest "h", using a switch/if...else if.

Comment: What is your selector? A child of h2/h3 or a sibling?

Comment: A child, i.e. it is within the heading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comma in selectors means "or". So you may do this :

```
$(mySelector).closest('h3, h2')
```

This will return 0 or 1 element, the closest if more than one match.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

So if I have `<h2><h3><a id="a"></a></h3></h2>` and write `$("#a").closest('h3, h2')`, it will give me the h3?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? BTW, why would you have one heading inside another?

Comment: That was just an example. What I actually need to do is select the nearest heading to my element, and there are loads of different headings on the page, so if I had just used `closest("h2")` and the closest heading was an `<h3>`, it would select the wrong one.

Comment: Well, not exactly. What I *really* need is, on a page full of headings with links in them, to select a link and then select the heading it "belongs" to.

Comment: If the element is within an H2, `closest('h3')` will return an empty array. So it should never return the wrong one unless you have nested heading elements (which I think HTML5 prohibits).